# Angular deferred loop

Tags: angularjs, deferred

I'm chasing my tail here. All I'm looking to do is return a string from the $scope.getPlacesTextRaw function.

```
$scope.getPlacesTextRaw = function(selectedPlace){

    mentionsFactory.getPlaceMetaData(selectedPlace).then(function(metadata) {
        console.log("here is our metadata", metadata);
        return metadata.description.replace(/ /g,"_");
    });

};
```

Another attempt:

```
$scope.getPlacesTextRaw = function(selectedPlace){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    mentionsFactory.getPlaceMetaData(selectedPlace).then(function(metadata) {
        console.log("here is our metadata", metadata);
        deferred.resolve('@' + metadata.description.replace(/ /g,"_"));
    });

    deferred.promise.then(function(string){
        return string;
    });
};
```

I'm calling getPlacesTextRaw from within a directive:

```
<mentio-menu
    mentio-for="'hashtag'"
    mentio-trigger-char="'@'"
    mentio-items="places"
    mentio-template-url="/places-mentions.tpl"
    mentio-search="searchPlaces(term)"
    mentio-select="getPlacesTextRaw(item);">
</mentio-menu>
```

Comment: how you calling function getPlacesTextRaw ? not from html like {{getPlacesTextRaw()}} ?

Comment: @That1guyoverthr: You are utilizing some asynchronous programming (be it using promises or callbacks or whatever), so you can't return a string. You can return a promise that gets resolved into a string. Depending on your usecase, you might also be able to return an object containing an empty string property, that gets assigned the actual string when ready).

Comment: @sss I updated my questions to answer yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ment.io team has updated their product to support promises.  Woot!

Answer (score 0):

so I thought :)
Please see here `https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D` second block

You have change approach a bit please see that demo: http://jsbin.com/kakim/2/edit

insetead of  `mentio-select="getPlacesTextRaw(item)` do `mentio-select="PlacesTextRaw"`

```
 $scope.PlacesTextRaw = "";

    $scope.getPlacesTextRaw = function (selectedPlace) {
        mentionsFactory.getPlaceMetaData(selectedPlace).then(function (metadata) {
            console.log("here is our metadata", metadata);
            $scope.PlacesTextRaw = metadata.description.replace(/ /g, "_");



        });

    };

    $scope.item = "test"

    function activate() {

        $scope.getPlacesTextRaw($scope.item);
    }
    activate();
```

Comment: Sorry @sss but I'm not understanding.  The jsbin isn't working (blank output).  I'm trying to implement your solution (in many different ways and I'm just perplexed)..

Comment: More specifically I just don't get what activate() is trying to do.  This example just returns a whitespace to the view because $scope.PlacesTextRaw = "" @sss

Comment: @That1guyoverthr output is blank because there is no code for your 'mentio-menu' directive, but please check console. activate() basically is a function which will run when your controller get active

Comment: Thanks for the help @sss.  this didn't work for me probably because I have a much more complex problem on my hands than I proposed.  It's hacked together a solution and since it's a terrible solution I'm gonna leave this unanswered.  Thanks again.